# Is the identity a permutation that commutes with all bijections of a set with more than two elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, permutations

If $|S| > 2$, then what can we say about the bijection $f_0$ of $S$ onto itself such that $f_0$ commutes with every bijection of $S$ onto itself? Of course, the identity commutes with every map; can $f_0$ be any other map as well?

Answer (score 5):

No. Think of bijections as members of $S_n$ (the symmetric group). [Here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Center_of_Symmetric_Group_is_Trivial) you can see that it has a trivial center.

Comment: The proof applies even if the bijections are of an infinite field too.

Comment: It would be better if you included a link. It useful keeping the site self-contained for the sake of link rot. (See, for example, [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6501/what-constitutes-a-trivial-answer/6505#6505) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835/on-answers-that-are-nothing-but-the-image-of-a-textbook/1837#1837)). (Also, going by the way that the OP has phrased the question, it would perhaps be helpful if you explained *how* to think of bijections as members of $S_n$.)

Comment: I have no idea why I said field. Weird.

Comment: @anon Drunk this early?